# Prove Harr wavelet orthonormal basis

Tags: real-analysis, integration, hilbert-spaces

Define $$h = 1_{[0, 1/2)} - 1_{[1/2,0)} \ \ \mbox{and} \ \ h_{(j,k)}(x) = 2^{j/2}h(2^jx - k).$$
Let $A = \{(j.k) : j \geq 0, k = 0, 1, 2, ..., 2^j -1\}.$ I want to show that $\{1_{[0,1]}\} \cup \{h_{(j,k)}: (j,k) \in A\}$ is an orthonormal set in $L^2([0,1])$. Then deduce that it is the orthonormal basis.

I sketch the some values of graph of $h_{(i,j)}$, but it is too confusing. I gather some information on the internet, and it is stated that the support of $h_{(i,j)}$ for different pairs of $(i_1, j_1), (i_2, j_2)$ is disjoint or completely contain in the other pair support. I see some examples of this fact from graphing $h_{(i,j)}$, but it is very confusing to build this rigorously. I find that it involves too much of index $i_1, i_2, j_1, j_2.$ Is there a simple way to notice and prove this fact ?

Next, after showing that set is orthonomal, I will show this set is complete, that is, for any Hilbert space H, the orthonomal set $\{x_\alpha \}$ is complete if for any $x$ with $x$ perpendicular to $x_\alpha \forall \alpha$, then $x=0$. First, I let $f \in L^2([0,1])$ with $<f, h_{(i,j)}> = 0$ for all $(i,j) \in A.$ But the complication of $h_{(i,j)}$ is troubling me, and I do not see why $f$ have to be $0$ (I am not sure if showing $f = 0$ a.e. is enough since Hilbert space is a set of equivalence class under a.e. relation between functions)

Please help !! I am really new to function space, and this things seems very hard to understand by myself.